# Did the Apostle Paul believe in the immortality of the soul?

Tags: paul-apostle, afterlife, souls, pharisees, immortality

The Apostle Paul used to be a Pharisee at one point, and Pharisees believed in the immortality of the soul [citationneeded], but then Paul became a Christian through a dramatic conversion, and I don't know to what extent his beliefs on the afterlife might have changed.

Did the Apostle Paul believe in the immortality of the soul? Can this question be answered objectively to any extent (on the basis of objective evidence)? Is there consensus among scholars and historians on this topic?

---

**Note**: Is this an "obvious" question? At first glance it might look so for many, but once you have garnered some experience exchanging thoughts with [Christian mortalists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_mortalism) and [Annihilationists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilationism) (e.g. see [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/27088/38524) & [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/73790/38524)), the answer to the question no longer looks so "obvious".

---

Related BHSE question: [What are the theological implications of Paul's continuing identifying himself as a Pharisee in Acts 23:6-10 despite being an Apostle of Christ?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/74210/38524)

Comment: There is such a straightforward answer based on 1 Cor 15 (which is a YES) I wonder maybe you meant something else by your question?  I notice that you're asking not just for intermediate state but for what comes after the day of judgment?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple - I mean from death onwards, which includes both intermediate state and post-judgement day afterlife.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple - I don't understand. If the answer is so obviously "yes", then why is Christian mortalism even a thing? The top user in terms of reputation on BHSE is a Christian mortalist!

Comment: Dang, I was going to answer your question, with the first line of the question (which is now the my top duckduckgo search for "Pharisee immortality". I only remember it because the alternative is so sad you see.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple - does *immortality of the soul*, by definition, require the existence of the soul in the intermediate state? Can a Christian mortalist be said to believe in the immortality of the soul if they believe that the soul will be immortal after judgement day (but not before)? I mean, if we adhere strictly to the definitions.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple - so should I reword my question as "was Paul a non-mortalist?" ?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple - perhaps this [intense debate](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/27088/38524) might give you more clarity on the context of this question (I posted an answer of my own [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/74125/38524); Dottard's answer [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/74132/38524))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133854/discussion-between-gratefuldisciple-and-spirit-realm-investigator).

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry. My bad. Have a wonderful day! :)

Comment: @Rajesh No worries.  Please comment my answer if you have any question.  Have a wonderful day to you too.

Comment: I thought the answer to this question was obvious, but you are correct, SRI. If some assert annihilation of the souls of the unbelieving then they are mortalists and do not accept the immortality of the soul. Your question is quite proper, after all. My mistake. I so assume that professing Christians accept immortality of the soul that my brain could not act in the opposite manner. Yes, can it be proved that Paul asserted soul immortality of all humanity ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Immortality of soul after the Day of Judgment

The certain hope that God has given to all Christians who truly believe in Jesus is that we will have a glorious body (and the accompanying soul) that Jesus the man had after resurrection, since as his adopted brothers & sisters we have also died and risen with him in baptism.

Whatever St. Paul previously believed as a Pharisee, the above hope was what Paul must have believed as well, as a Christian.  Paul was very clear in 1 Cor 15 (esp. [vv. 54-55](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2015%3A54-55&version=ESV)) that our glorified body is immortal.  The early church believed this as well, as this is the final line of [The Apostle's Creed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostles%27_Creed):

> I believe in ...
>
> ...
>
> and the life everlasting.  Amen.

As for the rest of the 2000 year history, I am not aware of any mainstream Christian denominations that don't believe in life everlasting for believers.  **Life everlasting for believers is quite a solid consensus**.  What's still debatable (since there is not enough Biblical data) is the fate of the souls of the damned: annihilation, temporary suffering in hell, everlasting suffering in hell in body+soul, everlasting suffering in hell in soul only, etc.

Whether one is a [Christian mortalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_mortalism) or not, the *result* is the same: **life everlasting**.  Thus for Christian mortalists one theory is that God would need to **create an eternal soul from scratch** while preserving some features of our earthly lives (taken from God's memory) to make our glorious bodies.  For the non Christian mortalists, God would simply let the immortal soul to be hypostasized with the glorious body, thus enabling the soul to experience a new, glorious and eternal existence.

#### Status of the soul prior to the Day of Judgment

Many recent evangelicals believe in the conscious existence of the soul prior to the day of judgment, as [my other answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/89401/10672) made clear based on careful exegesis of the whole of the New Testament by Michael Bird using Biblical theology approach and using the latest research of Second Temple Judaism.  He said that Paul wasn't as clear about the intermediate state as the final state, but he said we can make a good case that Paul believed in *conscious existence* in the intermediate state.

Catholic position is similar, but the believers's blessed presence in heaven with Christ during the intermediate state can be preceded by Purgatory.

In my opinion, it's the *result* that matters.  In his letters Paul indicated the *result*, not the precise mechanism or precise ontology of body and soul.  Depending on what the soul without the body is capable off (we only have theories) God may either let the soul to continue into the intermediate state without change, or God would need to fit that soul with a temporary partial something to experience Christ's presence and/or purgatory.

Christian mortalists who interpret Paul and the Biblical data differently will say that upon death, the soul is either unconscious or perishes along with the body.

Comment: But those who say that the unbelievers are annihilated, clearly do not believe that a soul is immortal.

Comment: @NigelJ Not that it's inherently immortal; God **alone** is inherently immortal(1 Timothy 6:15). "Souls" are not inherently immortal, but they are capable of becoming immortal(only if God gives them immortality). Thus, they are capable of being annihilated. :)

Comment: @NigelJ - Just so you have more context, Rajesh comes from a Jehovah's Witness background.

Comment: @Rajesh I do not believe that myself. My understanding from scripture is that God makes souls immortal. And they have this gift for ever and are responsible for it.

Comment: "*My **understanding from scripture** is that God makes souls immortal. And they have this gift for ever and are responsible for it.*" Which scripture?

Comment: "*Rajesh comes from a Jehovah's Witness background.*" That wouldn't help Nigel much. I may have grown up a JW, but I am in no way biased towards their teaching(e.g. I believe that Jesus is God, JW's do not), nor do I let the things I learned from them cloud my judgment; I am not an annihilationist because I was raised one. I am one because I have proved to myself that that is what the Bible teaches. :)

Comment: @Rajesh Thank you for the above comment on your own background. Personally, I cannot see any scripture that would suggest otherwise than I have stated. My apprehension of God is a matter of faith, not just words on the page. My apprehension of his eternal Being, likewise. And I have always known , as long as I can remember, that my soul is immortal. Matthew 25:41 'Go from me . . .  into the fire the eternal' Matthew 25:46 'And these shall go away into punishment eternal' [Both in literal - EGNT from Stephens Text 1551]